# ASP.NET MVC Core No executable found matching command "dotnet-bundle"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, msbuild

ASP.NET MVC Core No executable found matching command "dotnet-bundle"

I see the following in the Output Window when I Build my MVC Core WebApp. I can run my app with localhost and everything works well. This message at this time doesn't affect me on my localhost.  Is this something that I should be concerned with when I publish my app?

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(149,5): Error : No executable found matching command "dotnet-bundle"

Here's my project.json details...

```
   "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "Views",
      "Views/**/*.cshtml",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "Areas/**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Here's the answer to this question:

In tools section of package.json add this-

```
"tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.281",
```

Comment: Which `BundlerMinifier.Core` version used on your project? Also I want to see your `project.json` content for further examination.

Comment: Note I have the same problem, BundlerMinifier.Core 2.2.281

Comment: I don't know if it will help, I was able to publish from the command line using "dotnet publish" even though I have the same error, you might want to try.

Comment: John, Yes, I am able to publish now... I was working through some issues. But I still have the "No executable dotnet-bundle" message.

Comment: I've added my project.json details into my original question.

Comment: Any luck fixing this? I've hit this too

Answer (score 6):

same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067911/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-bundle-during-webdeploy-for-asp-ne/40068148#40068148)

- `tools` setting in  package.json

  - `BundlerMinifier.Core`

Comment: This should be a comment or you should have flagged this as a duplicate referring to the answer you linked to in your first line.

Comment: I'm thinking that since I asked this question many days before ...the other post should be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

one more thing to add is that after adding the BundlerMinifier.Core to the tools section in package.json file if you are using Visual Studio 2015 as described above, you need to do a manual package restore. Else VS keeps throwing a package version not found error. For some reason VS 2015 was not doing auto package restore when the new line was added to the tools section in the file.

BTW: Thanks for the original solution above.