# No executable found matching command "dotnet-bundle" during WebDeploy for ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, webdeploy

I am new to ASP.NET and I am trying to publish a web app. I have tried with 2 different hosts to do a web deploy but keep receving the error:-

No executable found matching command "dotnet-bundle"

What is this related to?

**Project.Json**

```
{
"dependencies": {
"Bitly.Net": "0.0.6",
"BitlyAPI": "1.0.3",
"BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.281",
"Common.Logging": "3.4.0-Beta2",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
"Parse": "1.7.0",
"Spring.Social.Twitter": "2.0.0-M1",
"Stormpath.AspNetCore": "0.7.0"
},

"tools": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},

"frameworks": {
"net46": {
  "frameworkAssemblies": {
  }
}
},

"buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
"preserveCompilationContext": true
},

"publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "**/*.cshtml",
  "appsettings.json",
  "web.config"
]
},

"scripts": {
"prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
"postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
},
"userSecretsId": "aspnet-ParseAppDashboard-20161008081***"
}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In **tools** section of **Project.json** add this-

```
  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.281",
    ....
```

On saving Project.json, VS2015 automatically restore packages.

If it doesn't worked then right click on project and click on Restore Packages option.

If this doesn't worked then try restoring using `dotnet restore` CLI command.

See if this helps.

Comment: That seems to have removed that issue. Thank you very much @Sanket

Comment: It helped me too, but I did additional step to fix the `Version for package 'BundlerMinifier.Core' could not be resolved.` error message, after the `No executable found matching command "dotnet-bundle".` one disappeared.

So, I right clicked on a project and hit the `Restore Packages` command.

Comment: @OlegBurov Thank you for sharing your solution. I had the same issue as you did, and after applying your additional step it solved my issue. Hopefully your comment will help others, as well.

Comment: Do we have any idea why BundlerMinifier.Core isn't included by default in a new ASP.Net core app?  (I suppose in theory I created my app as an ASP.Net Core 1.0 app, and have since upgraded to 1.1.  Could that be part of the problem?)

Comment: No @JoelB... I am not sure why BundlerMinifier is not included by default.

Comment: In case of ERROR: "Could not find ... user... \.nuget\packages\.tools" after editing of project.json simply delete project.json.lock file.. Visual Studio will recreate it and missing package will be downloaded.

Answer (score 31):

Since the end of 2016 (RC3 & later, VS2017 & later) move to `.csproj` file format, add

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="2.6.375" />
```

to an `<ItemGroup>`:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  ...

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="2.6.375" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Or create a new `<ItemGroup>` (you can have many of them) for your `DotNetCliToolReference` settings.

But look at https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundlerMinifier.Core for the latest version number

Comment: This is still not getting me past the same issue as the OP, I'm using core 2.0. (I have set default project to the correct project in PM console window too) - 2.6.375 is still the latest version at time of writing.

Comment: try `dotnet restore` after manually adding the BundleMinifier?
Does `dotnet bundle` work from a command line in the project directory?

Comment: How does this apply in a CI environment, you won't open VS there and click on save or something like that?

Comment: @David - say more? This answer doesn't require opening VS, it's a one-time fix to edit the project file and save it.

Answer (score 2):

You probably also need to add

```
"runtimes": {
"win10-x64": {}
},
```

to your project.json if you want to upgrate to core 1.1 (also change to correct runtime in the global.json file) I say this because I got the bundle error after upgrading my packages and app to 1.1 in VS2015.