# How to add tool section in .net core 1.1 csproj

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-1.1

> The command "dotnet bundle" exited with code 1

I am getting above error while publishing the .net core 1.1 app in VS 2017.

I suspect the issue to be related to tool sections which are missing in cs.proj file in VS 2017.

```
"tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.281"
```

In VS 2015 it used to be done as above as in the below link.
[No executable found matching command "dotnet-bundle" during WebDeploy for ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067911/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-bundle-during-webdeploy-for-asp-ne)

How to add tool section in csproj file in VS 2017 for .net core 1.1 app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [project.json to csproj mapping docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj) are your friend! Here's how the `tools` section maps over:

```
{
  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.281"
  }
}
```

becomes

```
<ItemGroup>
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="2.2.281" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. However i am getting another issue related to bower. **<Exec Command="bower install" />**, this is giving error, similar change for it as suggested in the answer is not working for it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly obvious when you look at your .csproj file how it's structured. But just incase.

```
<Project>
    ...Other stuff here    

    <ItemGroup>
      <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Your.Package.Name.Here" Version="x.x.x" />
    </ItemGroup>

    ...Other stuff here
</Project>
```