# Where to put "dotnet bundle" in .NET Core project (project.json replaced with *.csproj file)

Tags: json, .net-core, csproj

Since the most recent .NET Core (I am actually using AspNetCore 1.1.2) has replace the **project.json** file with ***.csproj** it is still not clear to me where to put the "dotnet bundle", precompile option.

```
    "scripts": {
        "precompile": ["dotnet bundle"]
    }
```

Prior the above block of json was found in the **project.json** file. Any clue where this goes? Is it already in some other configuration file? Below is a link that explains this change, and shows what the *.csproj file equivalent is to the project.json file:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj

As always, apologies for any incorrect vernacular here, .NET Core is new to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Target` and `Exec` [to accomplish this in `.csproj`](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5443#issuecomment-275195399):

```
<Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
  <Exec Command=”bower install” EnvironmentVariables=”Path=$(ExternalToolsPath)” />
  <Exec Command="dotnet bundle" />
</Target>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42099789/3561275) on how to get `dotnet bundle` to work with new `.csproj` format.